# How to update a zip file in Google Drive using Google Drive Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, zip

I am quite unexperienced with file compression and google drive api. In my project I am using [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) and Google Drive Api. The zip.js functions well because I download directly the generated zip file and my device can decompress it. Eventhough I don't add any extra data to the content of the zip, the zip file size is changed (doubled), and is corrupted when it is updated.

My function to generate a zip file:

```
function createZip(data,fileName,callback){
    var blob = new Blob([ data ], {
      type : "text/xml"
    });

    zipBlob(fileName, blob, function(zippedBlob){
        console.log(zippedBlob)
        // saveAs(zippedBlob,"test.zip") //this test.zip is a valid file.
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
           // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
           console.log(reader.result);
           callback(reader.result);
        });
        reader.readAsText(zippedBlob)
    })


    function zipBlob(filename, blob, callback) {
      zip.createWriter(new zip.BlobWriter("application/zip"), function(zipWriter) {
        zipWriter.add(filename, new zip.BlobReader(blob), function() {
          zipWriter.close(callback);
        });
      }, function(error){
        console.error(error)
      });
    }
}
```

My function to update the file:

```
this.updateFile = function(id, text, accessToken, callback) {
    var boundary = '-------314159265358979323846',
        delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n",
        close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--",
        mimeType = 'application/zip';

    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        delimiter + 'Content-Type:' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n' +
        text +
        close_delim;

    gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files/'+id,
        'method': 'PATCH',
        'params': { 'uploadType': 'multipart' },
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, },
        'body': multipartRequestBody
    }).execute(function(file) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback(file);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error)
        callback(error);
    });
}
```

I wonder if the FileReader corrupts the content because the `reader.result` is different than the original content of the zip. I use this function to read the file content:

```
this.readFile = function(fileId, callback) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileId,
        alt: 'media',
        Range : 'bytes=100-200'
    })
    request.then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (typeof callback === "function") callback(response.body);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error)
    })
    //return request;
}
```

The original content of the zip as text:

```
PKÊL    PV-A2.xmlUXñçûZÂÌZùì½m,I÷]þC£?I@ÌNøK¼=F °KÃ(­«Ýgz=Crçß+²ne§y¸¥U6... (some thousands characters more)
```

File reader content as text:

```
PK�U�L  PV-A2.xml�]�<��w�O1�+(���� �@�6`@+  �Ґ`��r��EÑ�������̊s"���0�..(some thousands characters more)
```

**SOLUTION**

Get base64 data from the zip file (remember to strip `data:application/zip;base64,` out):

```
    // saveAs(zippedBlob,"test.zip") //this test.zip is a valid file.
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
       // reader.result contains the contents of blob as a typed array
       callback(reader.result.replace("data:application/zip;base64,",""));
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(zippedBlob)
```

Add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` to multipartRequestBody and use the base64 content instead.

```
var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    delimiter + 'Content-Type:' + mimeType + '\r\n' +
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' +
    base64Data +
    close_delim;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `text` is the zip file which was converted to base64, how about this modification? I think that your script is almost correct. As a modification, it gives the encode method of the file using `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

#### From :

```
delimiter + 'Content-Type:' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n' +
text +
```

#### To :

```
delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n' + // Modified
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' + // Added
text +
```

#### Note :

- In my environment, I confirmed that the same error with your situation occurs using your script. And also I confirmed that when this modification is reflected to your script, the zip file is updated, and the file can be unzipped.

But if this was not the solution of your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's great that you have tried to investigate, thanks a bunch! I changed `reader.readAsText()` to `reader.readAsDataURL()` so `reader.result` returns a base64 string. Then I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. It doesn't encode the base64 string into the zip string content that is similar to the original (something like `PKÊL    PV-A2.xmlUXñçûZ`). The body of the modified file is exactly the base64 string.

Comment: It actually works. I forgot to remove `data:application/zip;base64,` from the `reader.result`. Cheers!!!

Comment: @phuwin I'm glad your issue was solved. I could also study from your question. Thank you, too!